# pig - window and rank functions with an case statement

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to write this SQL code into apache pig:

> rank() over ( partition by src_str order by 
>           (case when stat_cd = 'A' then 1 when stat_cd = 'B' then 2 else 3 end) asc) as rank1

Does anyone know a way this logic can be implemented in Apache Pig ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, logic will be pretty straight forward. You will need to create additional field by which you will rank your data.

```
A = LOAD '$SOME_DATA'AS (src_str:chararray, stat_cd:chararray, ololo:charrary);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE
--# loading all fields and creating a new in the end
    *,
    (stat_cd=='A' ? 1 : 
       (stat_cd =='B' ? 2 : 3)) AS rank; 

C = ORDER B BY rank ASC;
```

Hope it helps!